# What is the difference between if(isset($a)) and if($a) in php?

Tags: php

What is the difference between `if(isset($a))` and `if($a)` or `if_exist($a)` and `if($a)` in php?

Comment: Yes there is, nice way to learn something is to do it yourself. var_dump the results of the if-statements. Read php.net.

Comment: Please add whatever research you've done into the matter to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `$a = false;`:

`if ($a) {}` will return false, whereas `if (isset($a)) {}` will return true.

I do not know that if_exist you speak of. :)

Edit: Please check @Utkanos's answer for an excellent and more expansive explanation. :)

Comment: and **isset()** just Check out is variable empty or no, if its is empty return false.

Comment: same goes for value 0 or an empty string: isset will be true, but pure if will evaluate to false!

Answer (score 5):

`if (isset($var))`

checks that a variable has been set and that it has a non-null value.

`if ($var)`

assumes the variable has been set and checks instead for it having a truthy value.

PHP has no function `if_exist`. Perhaps you're thinking of `array_key_exists`, which returns true if an array contains a certain key.

Comment: `isset` checks if the variable has been set *and its value is not null*.

Comment: Forgot the non-null part - I almost exclusively use it just to check whether vars have been set or not. Edited - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`isset($var)` checks wether the variable `$var` is not of type `null` and returns a boolean `true` or `false`.

A variable is considered to be null if:

- it has been assigned the constant NULL.
- it has not been set to any value yet.
- it has been unset().

`if($var)` does an implicit type conversion to convert the `$var` from its original type to boolean which means it checks for `truthy` or `falsy` values.

To check wether a variable is `truthy` you can explicit convert it to a boolean:

```
$var = "foo";
var_dump((bool)$var); // outputs 'bool(true)'

$var = "0";
var_dump((bool)$var); // outputs 'bool(false)'
```

For a full list of how PHP handles the diffrent variable types see:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php